# Upload a file in admin and then download from the website Django

Tags: django, file, download

I am trying to create a website, where customer can upload a file in an Admin section, and after any person can download this file from the website. Preferably any files like pdf, exe, doc (is it possible?) I am able to upload a file in Admin and it shows it on the website. It downloads the file with a correct name (saved in media) but shows a failure , file missing.

So far I have :

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
class TEACHING(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    content = models.TextField()

    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    excercise = models.FileField(upload_to="files/", default='default value')

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def teaching(request):

    context = { 'teaches' : TEACHING.objects.all()}

    return render(request, 'blog/teaching.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
if settings.DEBUG:

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**teaching.html**

```
{% for teach in teaches %}    
    <a href="{{ teach.excercise }}" download>Download</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: do you have DEBUG=True in your app, also what is url that is generated in your href ( inspect element in browser)

Answer (score 0):

[Managing files docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#managing-files)

You should get URL from your File field

```
<a href="{{ teach.excercise.url }}" download>Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You are not providing `url` in `href`, so please change your `<a>` with following way

```
<a href="{{ teach.excercise.url }}" download>Download</a>
```